# Jquery -Validation, Moving to diffrent parts of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've three div tags in a page.

```
<div id = '1'>

</div>


<div id = '2'>

</div>


<div id = '3'>

</div>
```

When a user click on  tag, respective div will load,they all will be on one page with one submit button.

Now ,how to validate the div,i've to know which div the user clicked.

**update**

This is my vaidation script

```
 function x()
{

 var x = true;

 some validation script

 return x;

 }
```

Shed some light here,it will help me to go forward.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if you have javascript code, then please show it.

Comment: **one page with one submit buttons** do they all contain form fields? Have you tried `jquery tabs`?

Comment: Where are these `<a>` tags? And how do they relate to your `<div>` tags.

Comment: @Imdad:I've not tried,is there some thing called tabs in jquery.

Comment: Yes, try it. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: @ManseUK: I think it *is* valid in HTML5.

Comment: @James Wiseman: when <a> tag is clicked id is passed to jquery function to load that div,hope,it is clear.

Comment: @user1382687 if that is the case then you can keep the id of currently open div in a global variable

Comment: @Imdad:exactly the one,i was looking for,how do i do validation here.

Comment: See, if you want to validate only the current div then
you can do `$("#id_of_open_div input:first-child").val()` to get first **input** field's value within the current div. Similarly you can get next ones. For more details refer http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

You have to understand selectors to use jQuery well

Comment: @Imdad:# means id of div ,input means input tag,what is first and child,.val() means value in that input tag

Comment: `input` will return you all the input fields. so to choose first one we have to use `:first-child` you can also  use `:nth-child(1)` or  `:nth-child(2)` likewise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
var lastClickedId;

$('div').click(function()
{
    // Use a class to change appearance and track selected
    $('div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    // Or just track the id in a variable
    lastClickedId = $(this).attr('id');
});

function validate()
{
    alert('last clicked div ID was: ' + lastClickedId + ' aka: ' + $('div.selected').attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: :Above code add class and remove classes,i did not under stand.my question was,how to find the user is in which div?

Comment: Updated answer to demonstrate

Comment: :I'm using jquery tabs,here it is  jqueryui.com/demos/tabs,how to i change my function according to this.

Comment: If you have a new question then you should start a new question, don't ask it in the comments section.

Comment: :Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599929/jquery-validation-in-tabbed

Answer (score 0):

as i see you used id attribute with a number - its not valid in HTML5. 
you can use the id for this . some thing like this

demo : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pq4XE/)

```
 $('div').click(function()
    {
      alert('you clicked  ' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
```