# Jquery validation in tabbed

Tags: jquery, validation, tabs

Here is what i've been trying.

A form will have three tab ,like the above.

When ever use clicks particular tab and try to fill data,it has validate the empty vaidation for text boxes.

When user clicks the first tab and fill some data in text box id="textbox_four" ,then if he clicks the next tab,it data has to be there in id="textbox_five",the same when he click the third tab,it has to be there in "textbox_six",data has to keep passing.

http://jsfiddle.net/CuA9V/2/

It would be great,if you can shed some light here.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will keep them all in sync. I *think* that is what you are asking? lol

```
$('#textbox_four, #textbox_five, #textbox_six').keyup(function(){
    $('#textbox_four').val($(this).val());
    $('#textbox_five').val($(this).val());
    $('#textbox_six').val($(this).val());
});
```

Edit: you can check the selected tab during validation as below

```
$('#submitButton').click(function()
{
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs('option', 'selected');

    if (selected == 0) {
        // Do this
    } else if (selected == 1) {
        // Do that
    } else if (selected == 2) {
        // Etc
    }
};
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/trapper/CuA9V/5/

Comment: :If i click submit when i'm on first tab,it should post only that data.How to do empty validation.

Comment: Updated answer to show how you can check the currently selected tab

Comment: :Now my code is not working,can you put the working code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Detect the value onkeyup and copy the input to the other text fields:

```
$('#textbox_four').keyup(function(){

$('#textbox_five').val($(this).val());
$('#textbox_six').val($(this).val());

});
```

Comment: :is there any method to do that,i've posted my jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery to make it work and look better

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/